# Spring MVC uploads file to Tomcat home directory

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat

Spring MVC uploads file in tomcat's home directory for every upload, but never got deleted.

There are two issues,

1. Tomcat process will not have write permission to tomcat home directory in  PROD. So will get permission denied error
2. If we give permission then lot of files will be created but never got deleted.

Is there any way to get file uploads as byte[] from JSP to Spring MVC controller

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/13523/configure-tomcat-to-use-a-different-temp-directory-for-file-uploads/13698#13698

Comment: We have set -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/tomcat7-tomcat7-tmp. But files are not going to this directory but still goes to /var/lib/tomcat7 which is tomcat home directory

Comment: maybe `$CATALINA_TMPDIR` is not bound to the `java.io.tmpdir`? The link shoud apply to this case

Comment: why you  are uploading to tomcat home directory put it in some folder in home or d path in your instance ...

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to extend [`AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.html) overriding its inherited [`customizeRegistration()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.html#customizeRegistration-javax.servlet.ServletRegistration.Dynamic-) method.

An object of the [`MultipartConfigElement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/MultipartConfigElement.html) class can be provided in order to configure the multipart-related behaviour:

```
import javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class SpringMvcInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    . . .

    @Override
    protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration) {
        registration.setMultipartConfig(
                new MultipartConfigElement(LOCATION, MAX_FILE_SIZE, MAX_REQUEST_SIZE, FILE_SIZE_THRESHOLD)
            );
    }

    private static final String LOCATION = "C:/temp/"; // Temporary location where files will be stored
    private static final long MAX_FILE_SIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 5; // 5MB : Max file size.
                                                               // Beyond that size spring will throw exception.
    private static final long MAX_REQUEST_SIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 20; // 20MB : Total request size containing Multi part.
    private static final int FILE_SIZE_THRESHOLD = 0; // Size threshold after which files will be written to disk

}
```

See: [Spring MVC 4 File Upload Example using Servlet 3 MultiPartConfigElement](http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-mvc-4-file-upload-example-using-multipartconfigelement/)

Answer (score 0):

It's better to have a separate external folder for file uploads and map that folder in Tomcat as a location.

`<Context path="/uploads" docBase="C:/uploads/" />`

And it will be accessible from :

`localhost:8080/uploads`